# combined flatmap and forkjoin in one call angular

Tags: angular, nested, fork-join, flatmap

i have to do 5 api call, the first 2 are in sequence than the other 2 are in parallel and the last one come after the 2 in parallel, i'm trying to use flatmap + forkjoin but it seems that is not possible combine all in one call
is there any other alternative way?

my code is this...

```
public wrapfuncPOAddHead(response: any): Observable<any> {
    this.parsePOBatches(response.data)
    const request1 = this.createRequestAddHead();
    return this.widgetContext.executeIonApiAsync<IMIResponse>(request1)
}

public wrapfuncPOAddLine(response: any): Observable<any> {
    this.parsePOAddHead(response.data)
    const request2 = this.createRequestAddLine();
    return this.widgetContext.executeIonApiAsync<IMIResponse>(request2)
}


public createPO(suno: string, itno: string): void {

    this.setBusy(true);
    const request = this.createRequestBatchOrigin();
    this.widgetContext.executeIonApiAsync<IMIResponse>(request)
        .mergeMap(response => this.wrapfuncPOAddHead(response))
        .subscribe(response => response),
        (error) => this.showErrorMessage(error)
}
```

i would call wrapfuncAddLine in forkjoin?
how can i do that?

thank you

Comment: Can I see a clearer picture of the 5 Observables? Are they all different? Are they just different in terms of parameters? Which follows which?

Comment: http.get -> flatmap ( return second call ) -> flatMap ( return ForkJoin of two calls in sequence ) -> flatMap (return last call ) -> subscribe

Comment: thanks, it's working